# How to resolve a promise multiple times?

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, promise

It might sound weird, but I'm looking for a way to resolve a promise multiple times. Are there any approaches to make this possible?

Think of the following example:

```
getPromise() {
  const event = new Event('myEvent');

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }, 5000);

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }, 7000);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.addEventListener('myEvent', () => {
      resolve('some value'));
    });

    resolve('some value'));
  });
};
```

And then .then():

```
getPromise().then(data => {console.log(data)})
```

Should give the following result:

```
some value // initial
some value // after 5000ms
some value // after 7000ms
```

So I know there are libraries to stream data, but I'm really looking for a native non-callbak approach to achieve this.

Comment: Promises cannot be resolved multiple times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How to resolve a promise multiple times?

You can't.  Promises can only be resolved once.  Once they have been resolved, they never ever change their state again.  They are essentially one-way state machines with three possible states pending, fulfilled and rejected.  Once they've gone from pending to fulfilled or from pending to rejected, they cannot be changed.

So, you pretty much cannot and should not be using promises for something that you want to occur multiple times.  Event listeners or observers are a much better match than promises for something like that.  Your promise will only ever notify you about the first event it receives.

I don't know why you're trying to avoid callbacks in this case.  Promises use callbacks too in their `.then()` handlers.  You will need a callback somewhere to make your solution work.  Can you explain why you don't just use `window.addEventListener('myEvent', someCallback)` directly since that will do what you want?

---

You could return a promise-like interface (that does not follow Promise standards) that does call its notification callbacks more than once.  To avoid confusion with promises, I would not use `.then()` as the method name:

```js
function getNotifier() {
  const event = new Event('myEvent');

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }, 500);

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }, 700);

  let callbackList = [];
  const notifier = {
      notify: function(fn) {
          callbackList.push(fn);
      }
  };
  window.addEventListener('myEvent', (data) => {
      // call all registered callbacks
      for (let cb of callbackList) {
          cb(data);
      }
  });
  return notifier;
};

// Usage:
getNotifier().notify(data => {console.log(data.type)})
```

Comment: ok. That's what I was expecting. I just wanted to make sure if there is a way to achieve it. Maybe a workaround or something. All the member functions of my Library return promises except this one. So I wanted to make it similair. But of course you're right a callback fits perfectly. So thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Orlandster - I added an idea to my answer that makes a promise-similar-but-not-the-same interface that will notify multiple times.

Comment: How do you use this to actually push data to all "subscribers" - So if a Promise resolve I want to notify everybody. Currently the window.addEventlistener is out of context scope and I cant access any local class variables or pass data in with and Event (TypeScript)

Comment: @ppumkin - Please write your own question that shows the code for your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution in Typescript.

```
export class PromiseParty {
  private promise: Promise<string>;
  private resolver: (value?: string | PromiseLike<string>) => void;
  public getPromise(): Promise<string> {
     if (!this.promise) {
        this.promise = new Promise((newResolver) => { this.resolver = newResolver; });
     }
        return this.promise;
   }
   public setPromise(value: string) {
      if(this.resolver) {
         this.resolver(value);
         this.promise = null;
         this.resolver = null;
      }
   }
}

export class UseThePromise {
   public constructor(
       private promiseParty: PromiseParty
   ){
      this.init();
   }
   private async init(){
      const subscribe = () => {
         const result = await this.promiseParty.getPromise();
         console.log(result);
         subscribe(); //resubscribe!!
      }
      subscribe(); //To start the subscribe the first time
   }  
}


export class FeedThePromise {
   public constructor(
      private promiseParty: PromiseParty
   ){
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.promiseParty.setPromise("Hello");
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.promiseParty.setPromise("Hello again!");
        }, 2000);

        setTimeout(() => {
           this.promiseParty.setPromise("Hello again and again!");
        }, 3000);
    }
 }
```